# How to solve android element/attribute is not allowed here error?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, textview, imageview

I am a beginner and I am learning Android development. I am using Android Studio version 4.1.1 on Windows 8.1.

I am making a single screen happy birthday card app. When I opened the `activity_main.xml` file in Android Studio it is showing some errors although I have not made any changes to the default Android Studio code.

Also, when I replaced the default code with my project code, it continued to show the same errors. Errors are

- `element TextView is not allowed here`,
- `element ImageView is not allowed here`,
- `attribute:layout_width is not allowed here`,
- `attribut:tools:context is not allowed here`.

The `activity_main.xml` file is located in `app/src/main/res/layout`. I am providing a screenshot of the default code and also I am providing my project code below.

[image: Screenshot of the default android studio code with error highlighted in red]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:src = "@drawable/happy_birthday"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop" />
    <TextView
        android:text = "Happy Birthday"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:textSize = "36sp"
        android:fontFamily = "sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor = "FFFFFF"
        android:layout_margin = "20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text = "From, Me"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily = "sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize = "36sp"
        android:textColor = "FFFFFF"
        android:layout_margin = "20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try Invalidate caches & restart

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working @UsamaAltaf

Answer (score 1):

Try these 3 things:

- Build > Clean Project
- Build > Rebuild Project
- File > Invalidate Caches / Restart